# Cannot create Multiple Ids but yet I only have one

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

As you see I am creating a new class with one primary key I droped the db to recreate it but

```
public class CustomerContracts
{
    [Key, Column("ItemId")]  //This change the name of the column when you are using migration.  If you have a form created already, you have to change the connection in the for to aim the new column name.  

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string CustomerRef { get; set; }


    public int ContractTypeId { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    [DecimalPrecision(18, 2)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

But I am receiving the following error when I try to update the database.

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>   Applying explicit migrations: [201804260855058_firstmigration].
>   Applying explicit migration: 201804260855058_firstmigration.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Multiple identity columns specified for table 'CustomerContracts'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass32.<ExecuteStatements>b__30()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   ClientConnectionId:8aa18649-614e-4be4-a46d-fb780984d59f
>   Error Number:2744,State:2,Class:16
>   Multiple identity columns specified for table 'CustomerContracts'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.

Why would I be getting this error. As you can see, I am using only one key nor am I renaming it (it's a new table as I dropped the db).  Any help be appreciated.

Here is my migration I deleted the folder after i deleted the db and yet its still putting info into up and down.

```
 public partial class firstmigration : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.CustomerContracts");
            AddColumn("dbo.CustomerContracts", "ItemId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.CustomerContracts", "ItemId");
            DropColumn("dbo.CustomerContracts", "TeamId");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.CustomerContracts", "TeamId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.CustomerContracts");
            DropColumn("dbo.CustomerContracts", "ItemId");
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.CustomerContracts", "TeamId");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your migration?

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.CustomerContracts");
    DropColumn("dbo.CustomerContracts", "TeamId"); // Drop this first
    AddColumn("dbo.CustomerContracts", "ItemId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.CustomerContracts", "ItemId");
}
```

Comment: Why has it kept track of this though I do not understand i removed the database and deleted myu migration

Comment: That appeard to work but why should I have to do this manuall change

Comment: Looks like EF tried to add the new Id before it dropped the previous one.

Comment: I miss the edmx is there a way with ef6 to auto generate the classes as before ?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator

Comment: Arguably, if you're doing something like changing the PK on a table, you probably don't want too much automation, as it's a pretty significant change to want to do to a DB

Comment: So does ef create a generic ID column then if one is not defined maybe that is where my understanding is amiss strange other classes have same structure and was ok.